# How can I join together two queries on the same table?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a MySQL table, called **related_post** that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | post_1 | post_2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |     25 |     26 |
|  2 |     25 |     27 |
|  3 |     25 |     28 |
|  4 |     26 |     27 |
|  5 |     26 |     28 |
|  6 |     27 |     28 |
|  … |     …  |     …  |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I need to retrieve all the related posts for a given post ID.

If I supply '27', I want it to return a single column with "25", "26", and "28" as values.

Right now, I need to split it up into 2 queries:

```
SELECT post_1 FROM related_post where post_2 = 27;
SELECT post_2 FROM related_post where post_1 = 27;
```

I would like to know if it's possible to perform only one query to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a CASE statement to do this in one query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN post_2 = 27 THEN post_1 ELSE post_2 END as post
FROM related_post 
WHERE post_2 = 27 OR post_1 = 27;
```

Comment: this is faster than performing two `SELECT` queries and `UNION`ing them, correct?

Comment: @Redandwhite yes, it would be.

Answer (score 3):

Try `UNION`:

```
SELECT post_1 AS post FROM related_post where post_2 = 27
UNION
SELECT post_2 FROM related_post where post_1 = 27
```

`UNION` will also remove duplicates; if you do not want this then use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thanks! This didn't end up being the accepted answer (I was looking for a case statement), but +1 for being a very viable answer. Thank you